# DataAnalysis: How to simulate customer walk-ins for a given period in a fast food chain in R

Tags: r, simulation, data-analysis

I'd appreciate any tips, tricks, and/or R package recommendations for doing the following bit of data-analysis/data-science in the R programming language. I'm less of an expert in data analytics than I am in programming.

Simulate customer walk-ins for a given period. The simulations should take into account peak volumes at different times of the days and differences in week days and weekends.

Simulate customer purchases based on the customer walk-ins. Make assumptions on the average dollar price and variations for different times of the day.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

R has a group of random number generator functions for different distributions. For a given period of time, customers walking into a store can follow a Poisson distribution. For instance, if from 1 p.m. to 3 p.m., on average 1 person comes in every 2 minutes, we can use the `rpois()` function to approximate the amount of arrivals:

```
lambda <- 1
intervals <- 120/2
numCustomers <- sum(rpois(intervals, lambda)) #looks at 60 2-minute intervals
```

You could also alternatively treat the 2-hour period as 1 interval, with lambda=60. In either case, you have to specify your the rate at which customers come in during each time interval, but the Poisson can model the amount of customers in a fixed time interval once you do so. If you need help approximating the average customer traffic for the time in the day, cross-validated or data-science is probably a better place to post than here. It really depends on your data.

For modelling customer purchases, if you want to discretely measure whether someone buys or not, using a binomial distribution would work well. The `rbinom()` function allows you to do so. If we wanted to see out of the customers in that 2 hour window how many bought, where the probability of buying in that time period is 0.65:

```
customerSpent <- rbinom(numCustomers, 1, 0.65)
```

Once again, if you need help figuring out the distribution for which someone spends, this may not be the best place, try one of the other StackExchange sites. The larger point is that it depends on the structure of your data, and R has nice ways to allow you to simulate customer walk-ins once you know what distributions you want to use.

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks! Is there a name for this type of analysis that I could do a general search on, to learn more?

Comment: I didn't realize this could be tackled like a basic statistics homework problem. I wasn't sure if there might be industry related formulae and procedures, or if there is a specific type of analysis that one does on those types of problems. I do have basic statistics, and what you are saying makes sense, Thanks, that is helpful.

Comment: In general, Monte Carlo methods use repeated random sampling for complex problems to compute mathematically. Additionally, if you just search something like "Simulation in R" in google, you will find good literature and examples for how to create simulations in R. Here is one of the first links: https://web.stanford.edu/class/bios221/labs/simulation/Lab_3_simulation.html